# How to make out of function EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need help about EditText in android. 
In my app i have 2 editText fields. The firs is mandatory to make some calculations, the second is not mandatory it is avalaible only if checkbox is checked. My problem is that i cant make calculations if i don't put some value in secont EditText field. 
How can i disable it (out of function) the second field, and to be enabled only if checkbox is checked ?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your EditText by calling [`edittext.setEnabled(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) *(enable it by calling the same method with true)* and you can get the status of your checkbox by calling [`checkbox.isChecked()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked%28%29). Just combine the two to achieve what you want.

Comment: In my case is not working. It enables the field but still can't make the calculation !

Comment: Well, without seeing your code there is not much more to say. Edit your code into the question so we can see where the issue is.

Comment: I think i find one way of solving. Maybe is not the right one but works.

in try / catch i initialized: 

    secondVal = Double.parseDouble(editTwo.getText().toString());

now i deleted and initialized on checkBox check

    if (checkBox1.isChecked()){
     editTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     secondVal = Double.parseDouble(editTwo.getText().toString());
    }